# Which tool to create a sitemap to plan a future site?

Tags: sitemap, tools

I'd like to create a sitemap to plan a future site, and I'm looking for a tool to do it.

I'd like to create a list of all articles first.

Then a hierachy.

Then I'd like to put the articles on several places in the hierachy. I should be able to put one article at different places.

I'd like to have the ability to mark the articles in different colors whether they should come into the first version of the website or later.

Answer (score 1):

Any [mind-mapping tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map) will do.

I use [The Brain 7](http://www.thebrain.com/) (there is a free version).

Comment: A mind-map tool could do it, but it would be easier with a tool that fullfills the reguirements I explained, because with a mind-mapping tool I needed to do all this things manual which I don't like to.

Comment: @peterpurzelbaum Many mind-mapping tools *will* let you do that, which is why I suggested that particular tool. (Unfortunately, I don't think The Brain does.) Perhaps try http://slickplan.com/

Comment: I already tried slickplan and but it doesn't allow to manage articels and put them in several places in the hierachy, and of course if I can't make them I can't  color-code them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this great and simple web app: [writemaps.com](http://writemaps.com/tour/)

> WriteMaps provides an easy-to-use interface for creating, editing, and sharing your sitemaps.

Enjoy

NB: it's a free service